# Why is React Chunking not working?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to chunk my react app using webpack, but nothing loads and it says vendor.js says 0 bytes. What am I doing wrong? I think there is something wrong in my index.html. vendor.js and index.js are both located in the src folder. I've already tried following this, but no luck https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/368

Webpack

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
    vendor: './src/vendor.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor.js')
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: What version of webpack are you using?

Comment: Also is there any module referenced in vendor.js file?

Comment: "webpack": "^1.12.9",
 "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"

Comment: @WitVault vendor.js is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add all of your common dependencies into `vendor.js` via import, 
e.g jquery, lodash, post-css, jss or any others which you are using.

since you have not done that may be because of that your `vendor.js` file is of size 0 bytes.

Change your `CommonsChunkPlugin` to

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name : 'vendor',
 }),
```

Also you need to change your `index.html`

because in your webpack config you have

```
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
```

Here

```
filename: '[name].js'
```

means files will be generated by webpack based on entry names as `app.js` and `vendor.js`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/vendor.js"></script>  
  <script src="/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Error. `Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at app.js:1`

Comment: Just one thing are you able to see there are two files generated app.js and vendor.js?

Comment: Yes they are generated.

Comment: can you try changing it to new `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js', Infinity)`? Also load vendor.js first then app.js as I have done index.html

Comment: Only vendor.js is rendered and not app.js. plus I get the same error

Comment: Ok, I put vendor.js first and it worked, but I had a question. Isn't app.js rendering everything?

Comment: Yes you are correct but app.js is dependent upon vendor.js and it has to be loaded first. Suppose you want to use bootstrap library in your web-page, so bootstrap scripts -js and css has to be put first in ordering so that they are loaded first and then dependent files should be loaded.

Comment: Yeah so my index.html would have the css scripts, but isn't the point of chunking to only load the components when the link is visited? and if app.js is rendered wouldn't that load the whole application?

Comment: No realoading only fetch app.js not vendor.js. Your changes will be only in app.js and vendor.js will remain intact since you have done not any changes in third part libraries. So for the first time app.js and vendor.js will be fetched and for subsequent req only changed file will be requested which is app.js.

Answer (score 0):

change `new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor.js')` to 
`new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor','vendor.js', Infinity)`

or better be `new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor','vendor.[chunkhash].js', Infinity)`

I would recommend migrating to Webpack 2. [Refer migrating guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/)